# The service starts and then stops with message: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have developed a simple windows service using below code.
When I start the service, it takes about 20 seconds, the service does not start and I get the error message I mentioned on title.

Note: It logs "Starting..." in event log but looks like the code after that does not run. Please advise.

```
Dim eventId As Integer = 0

Private Sub OnTimer(sender As Object, e As Timers.ElapsedEventArgs)
    EventLog.WriteEntry("Monitoring the System", EventLogEntryType.Information, eventId)
    eventId = eventId + 1
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal CmdArgs() As String)

    EventLog.WriteEntry("Starting...") ' this line executes

    Dim timer As System.Timers.Timer = New System.Timers.Timer()
    timer.Interval = 60000 ' 60 seconds
    AddHandler timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Me.OnTimer
    timer.Start()
    Return

    ''''' some unused code below as I have Return
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank for response. I updated my code using Microsoft example. now it shows the same message immediately.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Your code looks ok now, and I've just pulled your code into a test application and it works fine for me locally.

Comment: It looks good to me either. I'm still struggling with it. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research more on SO, I found the problem was I was using the Debug build!!!
[See the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158371/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-tim)

Answer (score 2):

Windows gives a service up to around 30 seconds for the `OnStart` method to return. If it doesn't within this time, Windows assumes that the service hasn't started properly and gives you the error.

Your `OnStart` method never returns, as you have an infinite loop inside it. What you need to do is to create new thread in the `OnStart` method, start it, then return. The new thread should do any work you want the service to actually do.