# Topshelf Windows Service times out Error 7000 7009

Tags: vb.net, service, timeout, topshelf

I have a windows service programmed in vb.NET, using Topshelf as Service Host.
Once in a while the service doesn't start. On the event log, the SCM writes errors 7000 and 7009 (service did not respond in a timely fashion). I know this is a common issue, but I (think) I have tried everything with no result.
The service only relies in WMI, and has no time-consuming operations.
I read this question ([Error 1053: the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158371/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-tim)), but none of the answers worked for me.

I Tried:

- Set topshelf's start timeout.
- Request additional time in  the first line of "OnStart" method.
- Set a periodic timer which request additional time to the SCM.
- Remove TopShelf and make the service with the Visual Studio Service Template.
- Move the initialization code and "OnStart" code to a new thread to return immediately.
- Build in RELEASE mode.
- Set GeneratePublisherEvidence = false in the app.config file (per application).
- Unchecked "Check for publisher’s certificate revocation" in the internet settings (per machine).
- Deleted all Alternate Streams (in case some dll was marked as web and blocked).
- Removed any "Debug code"
- Increased Window's general service timeout to 120000ms.

Also:

- The service doesn't try to communicate with the user's desktop in any way.
- The UAC is disabled.
- The Service Runs on LOCAL SYSTEM ACCOUNT.

I believe that the code of the service itself is not the problem because:

- It has been on production for over two years.
- Usually the service starts fine.
- There is no exception logged in the Event Log.
- The "On Error" options for the service doesn't get called (since the service doesn't actually fails, just doesn't respond to the SCM)
- I've commented out almost everything on it, pursuing this error! ;-)

Any help is welcome since I'm completely out of ideas, and I've been struggling with this for over 15 days...

Answer (score 2):

For me the 7009 error was produced by my NET core app because I was using this construct:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
```

and `appsettings.json` file obviously couldn't be found in `C:\WINDOWS\system32`.. anyway, changing it to `Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "appsettings.json")` solved the issue.

More general help - for Topshelf you can add custom exception handling where I finally found some meaningfull error info, unlike event viewer:

```
HostFactory.Run(x => {
    ...
    x.OnException(e =>
    {
        using (var fs = new StreamWriter(@"C:\log.txt"))
        {
            fs.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Been searching for hours why my service wouldn't work, thank you so much!

Comment: @danny10846 happy to help! Just FYI since writing my answer, there were improvements done in .NET core and native support for windows services has been added, see e.g. [here](https://codeburst.io/create-a-windows-service-app-in-net-core-3-0-5ecb29fb5ad0). As a result we stopped using Topshelf entirely, so perhaps something for you to consider in case you are on .NET core.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the `7000` and `7009` issue, which fails straight away (even though the error message says `A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds)`) because of misconfiguration between `TopShelf` and what the service gets installed as.

The bottom line - what you pass in `HostConfigurator.SetServiceName(name)` needs to match *exactly* the `SERVICE_NAME` of the Windows service which gets installed.

If they don't match it'll fail straight away and you get the two event log messages.

Answer (score -1):

I had this start happening to a service after Windows Creator's Edition update installed. Basically it made the whole computer slower, which is what I think triggered the problem. Even one of the Windows services had a timeout issue.

What I learned online is that the constructor for the service needs to be fast, but OnStart has more leeway with the SCM. My service had a C# wrapper and it included an InitializeComponent() that was called in the constructor. I moved that call to OnStart and the problem went away.

Comment: Oops, sorry. After more thorough testing I found that moving initialization to OnStart causes other problems. It should stay in the constructor.

Comment: Please delete your answer if you think it is wrong, rather than leaving a comment.