# Windows could not start the Visual Studio Standard Collector service 150

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Visual Studio version I'm using is 2019 16.10.3. The Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150 is set to 'Automatic' but after a reboot it's still not started in the Services applet. I try to start and get

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I have added the regDword value of ServicesPipeTimeout in `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\control` and set it to Value 6000 and DEcimal but still no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try opening VS installer, and running a repair?

Comment: This message does not indicate that an error has actually occurred within the service. It simply means that the Services snap-in has timed out. I suggest you reading this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158371/error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-tim) carefully.