# Custom Powershell service won't start

Tags: windows, powershell, service

Good afternoon,

In our company, we are trying to change one of our current custom services, from NSSM to a custon-made with PS.

This code, already works on W7 and W10 1607 machines. But the same code, fails to start con machines with W10 1809.

This is the code (With other non related stuff):

```
$params = @{
    Name = "CertFix"
    BinaryPathName = "c:\winhttpcertcfg.exe -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -s HOSTNAME -a USER"
    DependsOn = "NetLogon"
    DisplayName = "certfix"
    StartupType = "Automatic"
    Description = "Service to give USER permission on the machine certificate"
}
New-Service @params
```

The error that it gives is:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          18/01/2023 18:28:35
Event ID:      7000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.store.domain.grp
Description:
The certfix service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7000</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-01-18T17:28:35.711754000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>31657</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="124" ThreadID="1664" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>hostname.store.domain.grp</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">certfix</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">%%1053</Data>
    <Binary>63006500720074006600690078000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          18/01/2023 18:28:35
Event ID:      7009
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      hostname.store.domain.grp
Description:
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the certfix service to connect.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Service Control Manager" Guid="{555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4}" EventSourceName="Service Control Manager" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">7009</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-01-18T17:28:35.711754000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>31656</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="124" ThreadID="1664" />
    <Channel>System</Channel>
    <Computer>hostname.store.domain.grp</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="param1">30000</Data>
    <Data Name="param2">certfix</Data>
    <Binary>63006500720074006600690078000000</Binary>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

The service is working on previous builds. But we are unable to make it work on 1809. Any advice would be great. Thanks in advance

I tried changing various ways on the BinaryPathName parameter, to fit the advice on the
[oficial New-Service page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-7.3)

but without success.

Comment: Not sure if it'll help, but here's a question about error `1053`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/158371/45375

Comment: Changed the image for error in text format. The code is as below, and is working on other builds